# Problem with new Thunderbird 115 install

Tags: software-installation, thunderbird

I installed Thunderbird following a major crash and after deleting the program, sudo apt-get purge thunderbird, then downloading >1000 messages.

This morning no sign of Folders let alone messages.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you download messages after purging the package?

Comment: From memory it did so f it's on accord